# How to open server-side generated file in same window and set filename

Tags: php, url, renaming

How to change picture name in php page i have file "photo.php" which get id of a picture.
and when i access link location name on title bar show as "photo.php". that means when i click save image as.. a name is "photo.php". i want its name for some field. I've tried
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');` but the header sent a picture as download I want to see picture in direct link of it URL.

```
include("conn.php");
    $userimgid = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE `userid` = '$userimgid' ";
    $sqlquery = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($sqlquery);
    if($num!=0){
            $type = mysql_result($sqlquery, 0, "mime");
            header("Content-type: $type");  
            $content = mysql_result($sqlquery,0,"data");
            echo $content;
    }else
        echo "Invalid requested.";
```

Thanks all answers

Comment: You probably need to do this via htaccess.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach using the `Content-Disposition` header is right. You just have to replace `attachment` with `inline` and it will open the image in the browser window.

**Edit:**
So that would be `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');`.

Comment: thanks Andreas it worked, i just overlook for it and it will be better if a picture name appears to title bar too.

Comment: Unless you wrap the image in a HTML document, it is up to the browser what to display in the title bar. In general this should be the plain filename.